# What is the equivalent of this step-by-step voice command in advanced scripting?

Tags: naturallyspeaking

I defined a step-by-step voice command:

[image]

What is the equivalent of this step-by-step voice command in advanced scripting?

I tried:

```
Sub Main
    SendKeys "^{Pad4}"
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Main
    SendSystemKeys "{Ctrl}({NumKey4})"
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub Main
    SendSystemKeys "^{NumKey4}"
End Sub
```

None of them works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Main
    SendSystemKeys "{Ctrl+NumKey4}"
End Sub
```

There may be other variants that work depending on the language of your OS and Windows version. If the above does not work, try this:

```
Sub Main
     SendSystemKeys "{Ctrl+Num4}"
End Sub
```

You can only use the ^ for Ctrl with SendKeys. SendSystemKeys & SendDragonKeys need the full form (Ctrl).

Comment: Thanks. This command writes `{Ctrl+Num4}` instead of sending the corresponding keys :/

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Try NumKey4 instead of Num4. Num4 apparently works because I am on a German Windows UI.

Comment: Thanks, it works. By the way any idea for http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a395857%20%20Dragon is welcome

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I'll take a look at them and answer them as time permits.